# Points of discontinuity

Tags: linear-algebra

What are the number of points of discontinuity of the function:

$[|x^2-4|]$

[] is greatest integer.

|| is mod function.

Also we have to find in range $(-4,4)$.

I am getting $29$ but answer says $28$.
Please help.

Comment: I suspect whoever wrote the answer thought that $0$ was a point of continuity. It would be without the absolute value. (But then of course $\pm 2$ would be points of discontinuity.)

Comment: I don't understand this function. $||$ is mod function, what does that mean? And does "greatest integer" mean rounding up? Like $[4.4]=5$?

Comment: @5xum To me, "greatest integer" is short for "greatest integer less than or equal," i.e., the floor function.

Comment: can anyone confirm the answer?

Comment: @AJ_ I can try if you explain what "mod function" means...

Comment: @5xum modulus, or absolute value.

Comment: @AJ_ Since the function is even, and the domain symmetric, the points of discontinuity are symmetric with respect to $0$, $\xi$ is a point of discontinuity if and only $-\xi$ is. So the number of discontinuities is even, if $0$ is a point of continuity, and odd if $0$ is a point of discontinuity. Since here the function is discontinuous in $0$, the number of discontinuities is odd. So $28$ cannot be right.